# Why is there no middleware in Erlang?

Tags: java, erlang

I asked a question earlier about ESBs written in Erlang or Java, and there didn't seem to be anything in Erlang, and only products in Java.

[What would be the best language in which to write an ESB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453641/what-would-be-the-best-language-in-which-to-write-an-esb/2453683#2453683)

I guess I find it difficult to understand why a language like Erlang has no such middleware products, especially seeing as it should be ideally suited to the job.

Update: There are in fact "some" middleware products for Erlang:

@aChristian suggested RabbitMq

Also, Erlang does have middleware, in fact it is a standard part of the Erlang distribution. It is called OTP.

Comment: Is not rabbitmq middleware of some sort?

Comment: Yes, you are right, rabbitmq is one.

Comment: The title of this question feels weird, since OTP - a platform that has been a core part of Erlang since the mid-nineties - has always been characterized as "middleware". Maybe the meaning of the term has drifted?

Comment: @RichardC - yes, good point, I didn't think of that

Comment: I guess you could argue that Erlang is middleware as well. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ESBs are used by large companies (E is Enterprise in ESB). Large companies tend to prefer the nr1 technology/vendor/consultancy company to reduce risk. See also "No one ever got fired for choosing IBM"

Comment: Yes, that's true. too bad Erlang hasn't been adopted by any big players

Answer (score 2):

Probably because a lot more people use Java, especially those people who write middleware products. As in "For every Erlang programmer, there are 300 Java programmers".

Comment: I'd love to actually know what that ratio is.. I'd put money on it being a whole lot more than 300 to 1

Comment: Yes, the number of Erlang programmers is miniscule. Maybe this is a good thing though. I still remember when Java was "miniscule" and simple to use

Comment: gid: I took the ratio from a statistic about job ads, with ~10K java job ads vs. ~30 erlang ads. Not exactly scientific, but also not completely fictitious.